# Giant LEGOs--that aren't QUATROs?

Tags: history, part-identification

We got a big tub of secondhand LEGO bricks, and included was a random pile of what appear to be giant LEGO bricks. They are a bit bigger than DUPLO bricks but smaller than QUATRO bricks and have an old style LEGO logo stamped into the studs. They're all the same size. What's the story of these bricks?

Here's a picture of them. I've put a DUPLO in the picture for scale ;-)

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think these are [LEGO Jumbo Bricks](http://www.miniland.nl/Historie/legoautos/samsonite/samsonite%20jumbo%20bricks%20eng.htm) from Samsonite.

[image]

Left to right: normal brick, duplo brick, Jumbo brick and Quatro brick.

Comment: Yep, looks like a match.

Comment: Are lego jumbo bricks of any notable value? or are they not worth any more than other used lego products?

Comment: Not a lot of Jumbo Bricks sell, but bricklink shows they sell for around $3 each