# Are LEGO Quatro compatible with larger bricks? Soft Bricks or other?

Tags: compatibility, duplo, quatro

There is a nice discussion [here](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/38/are-duplo-blocks-compatible-with-lego-blocks-in-any-way/9584) on LEGO+Duplo+Quatro compatibility.  I posted what I found [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/lego/comments/gu80d2/lego_brick_compatibility_with_other_lego_bricks/) where a LEGO storage block is the right dimension to be double a Quatro (4x Duplo, 8x normal).  However, a 2x2 Quatro will not stack on the storage block stud and the storage block does not have a working underside to stack/attach.

Are there bigger bricks out there that might work with a Quatro?  Maybe the Soft bricks?  I think the size is off on them and I don't have any to test out.  Are there working giant bricks out there that I am clueless on that might be compatible?

I have seen sources on the Samsonite jumbo bricks and they appear to not be compatible.  [Here.](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/4899/giant-legos-that-arent-quatros)

Is there a mythical "Octo" brick out there somewhere?  I don't think it can exist due the to bottom side of the Quatro brick (which does not have the standard single circle like Duplo and normal).